# Convert all IXmlNode ChildNodes into a string at once

Tags: xml, delphi, parsing, delphi-xe2

I'm parsing XML with `IXMLNode` components going through ChildNodes with code like `lChildNode := lCalendarNode.ChildNodes.FindNode(cNodeItemId)`, using `NextSibling` etcetera.

There is a part of my XML that I want to store in its entirety in a string, e.g. for

```
<RequiredAttendees>
  <Attendee>
    <Mailbox>
      <EmailAddress>user1@localhost.com</EmailAddress>
    </Mailbox>
  </Attendee>
  <Attendee>
    <Mailbox>
      <EmailAddress>user2@localhost.com</EmailAddress>
    </Mailbox>
  </Attendee>
</RequiredAttendees>
```

I want *this* in the string (with or without line separators/spaces, I don't care):

```
<Attendee><Mailbox><EmailAddress>user1@localhost.com</EmailAddress></Mailbox></Attendee><Attendee><Mailbox><EmailAddress>user2@localhost.com</EmailAddress></Mailbox></Attendee>
```

Is there a way to do this without having to parse all the underlying nodes?
Their structures and depth may vary, i.e. in this example the `<MailBox>` can have different forms.

Note that no name spaces are involved at all (neither are attributes at this stage, but since my XML comes from an external source, I can't bet on that staying so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (the OP) completely overlooked the `IXMLNode` XML property (Thanks [LLama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama))

Once I have my `var lNode:IXMLNode` pointing to the node , `lNode.XML` returns the string from `<RequiredAttendees>` to `<\RequiredAttendees>`. From that I can easily strip the outer XML elements.